# How to setup mock data from a method without pass parameters to the method

Tags: c#, moq

Thats my method and I just want to return a list of periods without caring for the parameters.

The lessonplannerAFactory needs to be isolated. I am only interested in getting a return value (periods) to test the other logic in the class.

```
 mockLessonplannerAFactory.Setup(s => s.Create(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, Enumerable.Empty<TimeTable>(), TimeTable.WeekType.A, DayOfWeek.Sunday,null)).Returns(periods);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `It.IsAny<>()` if you don't care about the actual value for the parameter:

```
mockLessonplannerAFactory.Setup(s => s.Create(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<TimeTable>>(), It.IsAny<TimeTable.WeekType>(), It.IsAny<DayOfWeek>(), null)).Returns(periods);
```

I can't tell what type the last parameter is, but you'll need to pass `It.IsAny<>()` for that one if your code under test doesn't pass null for that parameter.